# I am trying to install Kivy library with base and examples using pip, but the installation fails with an error related to the subprocess

Tags: pip, kivy, version

```
talha@DESKTOP-1L2UFDM MINGW64 /e/kivygui
$ python -m pip install "kivy\[base\]" kivy_examples
Collecting kivy\[base\]
   Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
   Installing build dependencies: started
   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

\[10 lines of output\]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-67.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,\<=0.29.28,\>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev\~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev\~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1, 0.6.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev\~=0.4.5
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I was trying to install kivy using gitbash but it shows this error repeatedly. I have upgraded my pip to latest version and have done everything else but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

There are no whl files available for python 3.11. I would suggest you try using python 3.10 instead.